# How to conditional format with multiple criteria (Excel Pivot table)

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, pivot-table

I have an Excel pivot table with no set boundaries (boundaries depend on what slicer option the user select).

In Column A: I have the store information such as daily sales volume and other value information. Since there are countless stores, this information repeats for each store. Sales_Volume column is placed in the VALUES section area in PivotTable Fields (Along with other columns that are also placed in the VALUES section, but I am only concerned with Sales_Volume column).

In Column B - xxx: I have the daily dates in the COLUMNS section area in PivotTable Fields so starting from Column B contains the Sales_Volume information for that day (Along with other values,but I am only concerned with Sales_Volume column). Every 9th row starting from row 13 contains the Sales_Volume value for that day.

What I want is for the conditional formatting to search for the the word "Sales_Volume" in Column A and for that Row color the cell red for any values in that row that are less than 200.

Does that makes sense? So ONLY every 9th row starting from row 13 would contain the conditional formatting (if the values are less than 200 in those specific rows only).

Any help would GREATLY appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution if anyone is interested:

I used the same formula listed here: "=AND(B6<200, $A6="Sales_Volume")"
however, my fix came from selecting the entire workbook from the first row that I wanted the conditional formatting to be set on so my selected range was:
B6 - XFD1048576 and voila!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a helper column could work for you...create another column with the formula of `=AND(A1="Sales_Volume",B1<200)`. This would either return `TRUE` or `FALSE`, and you could conditionally format that column.

Comment: The issue with that is it would only check for B1 (this is incorrect also, the sales volume data is store in B9 and repeats every 9th row so B9, B22, B35... and so on)

Comment: ...just drag the formula down.

Comment: you are still not understanding what I am looking for. That solution would only be for one day (one column). I need it for every single day for which the user selects. Example: B9 contains the sales volume information for day, but C9 for day 2, D9 for day 3, E9 for day 4... and so on.

Comment: Basically, I only want the conditional formatting for the ENTIRE rows where column B rows = "Sales_Volume"

Comment: alright big dawg it was tough to infer that from your description...can you add a table to your post to better help visualize what you want?

Comment: I apologize deeply for the confusion. I tried my best to word in a way so it would not create confusion. Also I am not sure how to add a table here so I took a screenshot of the excel document and uploaded to imugr. I hope that is not against the TOS for stackoverflow. Here is the link:

http://imgur.com/a/Br3oC

Comment: So I would only want the conditional formatting on row 6 and 15 since those rows contain the word "Sales_Volume" in Column A. Additionally, the conditional formatting would affects cells C6, E6, F6, H6, I6, K6, L6, N6, O6 since those cells are less than 200. (Same thing for row 15 where cells are less than 200)

Comment: I see. Before I theorize another solution, I would recommend checking out this SO post which asks a very similar question. Let me know if this still doesn't help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184339/excel-2007-conditional-formatting-with-2-conditions-one-based-off-another-colum

Comment: They are using the same solution that you pointed out. If i use this formule: "=AND(B6<200, $A6="Sales_Volume")". the conditional formatting works, but only for row 6. Row 15 has no conditional formatting.

Btw, I REALLY appreciate your help and time with this!